# routing: discriminate routes using regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, routes, constraints

This is for curiosity, but here's a case I faced this morning.

I want to discriminate routes based on a regex:

```sh
http://localhost:3000/teams/13/calendars/12
↳ Calendar#show

http://localhost:3000/teams/13/calendars/Aid9zeAhZos9zo58
↳ Calendar#secret_show
```

We cannot do something like:

```rb
resources :teams do
  resources :calendars
end

get '/teams/:team_id/calendars/:slug', to: 'calendars#secret_show', constraint: { slug: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]{16}\z/ }
```

Because `/teams/13/calendars/p0eiFDShzu132zea` still points to `Calendar#show` (*p0eiFDShzu132zea* being recognized as a Calendar's id)

[Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints) does not mention if we're able to use `constraint:` with `resources`.

We cannot restrict `:id` to match a regex, none of these are working:

```rb
resources :teams do
  resources :calendars, constraint: { calendar_id: /\A\d+\z/ }
  # nor
  resources :calendars, constraint: { id: /\A\d+\z/ }
end
```

#### How could we discriminate routes based on a regex and redirect to different controller's actions ?

---

If it can help anyone, here's some behavior I've noticed:

1. routes are treated from top to bottom

This works:

```rb
# route bellow will be tested before the resources blocks
get '/teams/:team_id/calendars/:slug', to: 'calendars#secret_show', constraint: { slug: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]{16}\z/ }

resources :teams do
  resources :calendars
end
```

2. Being as restrictive as possible may help you:

Kind of obvious, but the example above also works. (I'd still stick to the previous example until someone provides a better way of handling that).

```rb
resources :teams do
  # :show action isn't present, so /teams/13/calendars/ziao9sianzjUszi4 will be routed to the next matching route
  resources :calendars, only: %i( index create )
end

# here's our matching route
get '/teams/:team_id/calendars/:slug', to: 'calendars#secret_show', constraint: { slug: /[a-zA-Z0-9]{16}/ }
```

Comment: Why do you need separate routes? Is it a one time token or something?

Comment: It's a link generated in order to bypass the authentication and access the resource with only read privileges. It may be a naive approach to implement this, but that's another problem ahah

Comment: You already have a working solution, which is exactly what I would have recommended/used to keep this simple: Routes are defined top-to-bottom. Just define the `'calendars#secret_show'` route first.

Comment: However, I'd suggest that this is potentially a poor choice of design pattern -- maybe you could include some sort of authentication token (a `JWT`?) in the URL parameters to handle this, or maybe just make that endpoint public?!

Comment: JWT is a great recommendation, thanks !